# Count total mentions of multiple values from closed workbook

Tags: excel, vba, function, excel-formula

I am using this formula to pull data from another workbook. This is repeated hundreds of times to count how many times a particular domain (there are hundreds of domains) has been used in the other sheet.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"'E:\[OtherSheet.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1:ZZ500";"'E:\[OtherSheet.xlsx]Sheet2'!A1:ZZ500";"'E:\[OtherSheet.xlsx]Sheet3'!A1:ZZ500";"'E:\[OtherSheet.xlsx]Sheet4'!A1:ZZ500";"'E:\[OtherSheet.xlsx]Sheet5'!A1:ZZ500";"'E:\[OtherSheet.xlsx]Sheet6'!A1:ZZ500";"'E:\[OtherSheet.xlsx]Sheet7'!A1:ZZ500";"'E:\[OtherSheet.xlsx]Sheet8'!A1:ZZ500";"'E:\[OtherSheet.xlsx]Sheet9'!A1:ZZ500"}),D2))
```

This counts the number of times "D2" appears in the other workbook (across nine different sheets). This code is copied for "D3" "D4" and so on, hundreds of times.

There are a number of problems.

1) The other workbook has to be open, otherwise the data will not update (even with the exact path, INDIRECT will not allow updates).

2) If both sheets are open it updates every time you do anything, even copying and pasting cells, or inserting new cells. "Manual" formula updates are not able to be used as there are other dynamic variables besides this one (that don't slow down Excel) that need to be recalculated often.

3) From what I understand, INDIRECT and other related functions are single-threaded, which, even with a i7-8700k processor and 32gb RAM, with 64-bit Excel, makes the recalculation insanely slow.

4) I tried lowering the "scanned area" dramatically, but it doesn't speed it up. ZZ10000 vs ZZ500 doesn't make a difference, they're both equally slow.

A workaround is to keep one sheet open, update it, then open both when I need to have an 'overall' view. If one sheet is closed, Excel works fine as it is not having to constantly recalculate. Preferably I'd like to keep both sheets open without such a dramatic slow down.

From dozens of hours of research, I've sort of come to the conclusion that it is not possible to do this a fast way without using VBA. But I can't find any VBA function to replicate the code above.

I'm open to non-VBA based solutions as well.

Comment: What Excel version do you have? take a look at [Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/power-query-overview-and-learning-ed614c81-4b00-4291-bd3a-55d80767f81d?omkt=en-US&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: @Ricardo Diaz I use Excel 2013 64-bit. I will look into this, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yeah take a look. sounds to me it's the way to go. Post any question you may have.

Comment: What about [SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ee692882(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) (DAO/ADO)? Data should be stored in a database (e.g. Sql Server)! You can fetch the data in excel with a data-source.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher the data from the "other" workbook needs to be easily accessible and editable. I'm constantly updating both sheets. Not really sure if SQL would be proper for this function.

Comment: Sql and data are best friends! If data stored in a real db (not excel). you just need to sync changes from sheets back to db. Start with sql on ranges (see link), then upgrade to db later.

Answer (score 0):

You could use python's pandas module to solve this issue. It is much easier to work with using pandas's dataframe and you have no issue accessing a workbook even if it is closed. Just my two cents worth.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, sadly, I have never coded in Python, I know only PHP at a decent level and a bit of JS.